# Jacksonparser parser issue: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, spring, parsing, jackson

From a client, I am calling a REST service. The operation performed is POST. The REST service is processing the data but the response is not properly converting in a client application.

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> response = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};
                    ResponseEntity<List<String>> responseEntity = atomRestTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, response);
                    warningMessages = responseEntity.getBody();
```

I am getting the following error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]) at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

### Response Sample JSON - List of String

["warningmessage1", 
 "wanringmessage2"]

The service can return empty list as response. Does that creating the problem?

Comment: Please post sample JSON.

Comment: Response Sample JSON - List of String

["warningmessage1", "wanringmessage2"]

The service can return empty list as response. Does that creating the problem?

Comment: START_OBJECT just means an opening curly brace `{`. Your sample JSON cannot be the full picture as it has no curly braces at all.